# Why are all the VR apps upside down?

Tags: android, virtual-reality

I recently got a VR headset and the creators didn't configure it properly, I went to [this website](https://vr.google.com/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/) and adjusted it until it was perfect, and scanned the QR code it gave me with the Google Cardboard app. But whenever I go into an app, it is upside down and not split into 2 sides of the screen for the 3D effect. What am I doing wrong? Here are my settings, I went off the info that the box the headset came in gave me.

`Screen to lens distance (mm): 44
Inter-lens distance (mm): 60
Vertical screen alignment: Center
Distortion coefficients:
     k1: 0.001
     k2: 0.001
Field-of-view angles:
     Outer (°): 100
     Inner (°): 100
     Top (°): 100
     Bottom (°): 100`

I am using the VR SHINECON 4 headset. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So it's just a holder for a phone? Turn the phone upside down?

Comment: The entire view is upside down. When I turn it over it doesn't tilt the view. Imagine looking at the world right side up, then doing a handstand and still seeing the world right side up.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem, I just created a new profile for my headset twice and it still isn't working.

Comment: Although, mine is only for text, the apps all seem to use relative positioning for everything but text.